# border-bottom-width in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to set the width's for the border using jQuery, so it'll be adjusted to the screensize.

What I'm using right now is:

```
$("#content").css("border-bottom-width", "(1/20)*theHeight", "border-right-width", "(1/10)*theWidth", "border-left-width", "(1/10)*theWidth", "border-top-width", "0");
```

But this does not seem to do the trick. I know values theHeight and theWidth are filled, so that can't be the problem.

What am I doing wrong? If it's a really lame bug then I'm really sorry for being such a noob.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be like this:

```
$("#content").css({"border-bottom-width": (1/20)*theHeight, "border-right-width": (1/10)*theWidth, "border-left-width": (1/10)*theWidth, "border-top-width": 0});
```

The problem is that you're, first of all using the css() wrong. If you have more than one css properties then you need to make it an objet {key: value, key: value}. Second, if you put variables and calculations in quotes, the result will be just plain text.

Comment: Well spotted! +1 As a general rule, it  good to explain what needs to be changed (like what you commented underneath my answer) so people get it, and vote.

Comment: @Pekka Yes thanks, will think of that in the future. Btw, now I will give you +1 since your edit :)

Comment: @tbleckert - The reason someone may step in and get more votes is the *quality* of the answer, let me offer some helpful critiques here: 1) Your code scrolls off - when it could be formatted to clearly see what's going on. 2) There's *no* explanation as to what was wrong (quotes and object literal formatting). 3) Also if possible provide links to the user for further reading (optional, of course)...we want to teach them to fish, not fix individual pieces of code.  Remember: nothing stops you from improving your answer once it's posted...and you haven't done that unfortunately.

Comment: @Nick Craver thanks for that. The reason why I don't edit my answer is that there already is lots of good explanation in here.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you have your values in quotes and in the wrong format, just removes the quotes and make your argument an object, like this:

```
$("#content").css({"border-bottom-width": (1/20)*theHeight,
                   "border-right-width": (1/10)*theWidth, 
                   "border-left-width": (1/10)*theWidth, 
                   "border-top-width": 0});
```

The format for an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals#Object_Literals) is always `{ key: value, key2: value2 }`.  To be safe, quote your keys, since `border-bottom-width` isn't a valid key (because of the `-`), but `"border-bottom-width"` is just fine.  Also you can simplify it a bit, like this:

```
$("#content").css({"border-bottom-width": theHeight/20,
                   "border-right-width": theWidth/10, 
                   "border-left-width": theWidth/10, 
                   "border-top-width": 0});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"(1/20)*theHeight"
```

isn't it this:

```
((1/20)*theHeight)
```

so do it like this:

```
.css({"border-bottom-width": (1/20)*theHeight,
                   "border-right-width": (1/10)*theWidth, 
                   "border-left-width": (1/10)*theWidth, 
                   "border-top-width": 0});
```